# CButton CDC::SetBkColor not doing anything?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

On subclassing CButton, I want the color of the button to increment each time the button is pressed.  But the following is doing nothing to the background color.  However, the text shows "c" to increment.  thx

```
void CMyButton::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point) 
{
    CButton::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);
    static int c;

    CString s;
    s.Format("left:  %d", c*50);
    this->SetWindowText(s);

  ////// Neither of the following change the background color   
    //CPaintDC dc(this);
    //dc.SetBkColor(0x0 + c*50);
    CDC *dc= GetDC();
    dc->SetBkColor(0x0 + c*50);

    c++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change how your button is drawn, you should implement `CMyButton::DrawItem` (overriding `CButton::DrawItem`), and do the drawing there. In `OnLButtonDown`, you'll just do something like:

```
c++; 
Invalidate();
```

You'll want `c` to be a member of `CMyButton`, not local to `OnLButtonDown`.

Comment: Is there no way to work with the button graphic MFC supplies and change the background color there?  Using "DrawItem" requires me to implement all the graphics.

Comment: @jdl: Offhand, I don't remember for sure, but I seem to recall being able to invoke `CButton::DrawItem`, then doing drawing of my own to overwrite parts of what it drew.